# Exact Meaning of the parameters given to initialize MSER in OpenCV 2.4.x?

Tags: opencv, mser

OpenCV reference manual (2.4.x) states that the constructor that initializes MSER requires the following parameters:

delta, min_area, max_area, max_variation, min_diversity, max_evolution, area_threshold,
min_margin, edge_blur_size.

**I am dealing with grayscale images. What is the use of the parameters "delta", "max_variation" and "min_diversity"? What property of an MSER do these parameters help control?**

I have tried a lot to find the exact answer to this and I could only find a little information on the following pages (none of which was particularly useful in telling me what exactly do these 3 parameters control):
1. [OpenCV wiki](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/MSER)
2. [Wikipedia description of MSER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)
3. [MSER questions on STackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mser)

Please help!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am going to presume that you know the basics of how MSER feature detection works (if not, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions), and short recap follows).

You have two types of MSER regions, positive and negative.

First type, you get by thresholding with all intensities (for grayscale images, `0` to `255`). E.g. for a threshold `T = 100`, all pixels with intensity `< 100` are assigned `black`, or `foreground`, and all pixels `>= 100` intensity are `white` or `background`.

Now, imagine you're observing a specific pixel `p`. At some threshold, let's call it `T1`, it will start belonging to the foreground and stay that way until `T=255`. At `T1` a pixel will belong to a component `CC_T1(p)`. `5` gray levels later, it will belong to the component `CC_(T1+5)(p)`.

All of these connected components, obtained for all the thresholds, are potential candidates for MSER. (Other type of components is obtained if you reverse my `black/foreground` and `white/background` assignments for thresholding).

**Parameters** help decide which potential candidates are indeed maximally stable:

- **delta**

  For every region, *variation* is measured:

  `V_T = (size(CC_T(p))-size(CC_{T-delta}(p)))/size(CC_{T-delta}(p))`

  for every possible threshold `Ti`. If this variation for a pixels is a local minimum of a variation, that is, `V_T < V_{T-1}` and `V_T < V_{T+1}`, the region *is maximally stable*.

  The parameter *delta* indicates through how many different gray levels does a region need to be stable to be considered maximally stable. For a *larger delta*, you will get *less regions*.

  ***note:*** In the [original paper](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/bmvc2008/proceedings/2002/papers/113/full_113.pdf) introducing MSER regions, the actual formula is:

  `V_T = (size(CC_{T+delta}(p))-size(CC_{T-delta}(p)))/size(CC_T(p))`

  The OpenCV implementation uses a slightly different formula to speed up the feature extraction.
- **minArea**, **maxArea**

  If a region is maximally stable, it can still be rejected if it has less than *minArea* pixels or more than *maxArea* pixels.
- **maxVariation**

  Back to the variation from point 1 (the same function as for delta): if a region is maximally stable, it can still be rejected if the the regions variation is bigger than *maxVariation*.

  That is, even if the region is "relatively" stable (more stable than the neigbouring regions), it may not be "absolutely" stable enough. For *smaller maxVariation*, you will get *less regions*
- **minDiversity**

  This parameter exists to prune regions that are too similar (e.g. differ for only a few pixels).

  For a region `CC_T1(p)` that *is* maximally stable, find a region `CC_T2(p)` which is the "parent maximally stable region". That means, `T2 > T1`, `CC_T2(p)` is a maximally stable region and there is no `T2 > Tx > T1` such that `CC_Tx(p)` is maximally stable. Now, compare how much bigger the parent is:

  `diversity = (size(CC_T2(p)) - size(CC_T1(p))) / size(CC_T1(p))`

  If this `diversity` is *smaller* than *maxDiversity*, *remove* the region **`CC_T1(p)`**. For *larger diversity*, you will get *less regions*.

  (For the exact formula for this parameter I had to dig through the program code)

Comment: Perfect answer ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Flayn I know this is a very late response to your comment, but OpenCV in general has some problems with the MSER implementation (or at least had a couple of versions ago, and that steadily through several versions). The regions it returns are not even always maximally stable by definition...

Comment: @penelope: Do you know if OpenCV3.0 fixed the MSER implementation? How about the implementation in VLFEAT? Or do you know another reliable implementation of MSER (C/C++ prefer)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @THClem Again, quite sure this is too late, but... No idea for OpenCV3.0, I did not check the newer code (the only way to check is to test their outputs...). VLFeat is good. I use my own implementation, so can't suggest anything...

Comment: @penelope Thanks very much for this very thorough explanation. For people who are trying to follow it very closely, I just wanted to point out what I think are a few minor errors:
(1) The foreground/background determination is made by `< T` and `>= T` respectively (not `<= T` and `> T`)
(2) The variance calculation takes the _absolute_ value of `size(CC_T(p))-size(CC_{T-delta}(p))`
(3) The minimum variance requirement is the opposite of what's given, i.e. it should be: `V_T < V{T-1}` and `V_T < V{T+1}`
(4) In the edge case T = 255, only `V_T < V{T-1}` is required

Comment: @Danny Thanks for pointing this out :) I return to this question approximately once a year apparently; I edited your corrections (1) and (3) into the question. I agree with the edge case (4) of course, but this is a typical way to handle edge cases. As for (3), you will notice that a `size(CC_T(p))` will _always_ be larger than `size(CC_{T-delta}(p))` for any delta (you always progress from "smaller" towards "larger" blobs), so the difference is always positive and the absolute value not necessary.

Comment: How can we set these in opencv v3.6 or earlier for Python?  v3.7 seems to have added set functions, but that version isn't available to me yet.  For v3.6, setting them in the constructor according to the docs throw errors.

Answer (score 12):

- **Delta** delta, in the code, it compares
      `(size_{i}-size_{i-delta})/size_{i-delta}`. default 5.

  - **MinArea** prune the area which smaller than minArea. default 60.
  - **MaxArea** prune the area which bigger than maxArea. default 14400.
  - **MaxVariation** prune the area have simliar size to its children. default 0.25
  - **MinDiversity** trace back to cut off mser with diversity < min_diversity.
    default 0.2.
  - **MaxEvolution** for color image, the evolution steps. default 200.
  - **AreaThreshold** the area threshold to cause re-initialize. default 1.01.
  - **MinMargin** ignore too small margin. default 0.003.
  - **EdgeBlurSize** the aperture size for edge blur. default 5.
  - **Mask** Optional input mask that marks the regions where we should detect
     features

Comment: Thanks! but what does  (size_{i}-size_{i-delta})/size_{i-delta} in the definition of delta mean? What does size_{i} stand for? 

That's the big mystery to me. Please help!

Comment: Thanks for writing down the defaults. It is so hard to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my question thanks to [this](http://www.openimaj.org/openimaj-image/image-local-features/apidocs/src-html/org/openimaj/image/feature/local/detector/mser/MSERDetector.html#line.288) link.

MSERs are obtained by varying the intensity threshold T from 0 to 255. Delta decides the least count of that variation. So, size{i} means the size or area of region with intensity value i in a grayscale image.

Will get back with an explanation of MaxVariation and MinDiversity soon.

Comment: the link is now dead

Answer (score 3):

Matlab has an almost identical function MSER. In [Mathworks](http://es.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) you can find very well explained what are those parameters for, in my opinion.

I will copy the 2 inputs definitions you ask for (there are no options, in Matlab, for color images):

- **_delta**. Step size between intensity threshold levels, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'ThresholdDelta' and a numeric value in the range (0,100]. This value is expressed as a percentage of the input data type range used in selecting extremal regions while testing for their stability. Decrease this value to return more regions. Typical values range from 0.8 to 4.
- **_max_variation**. Maximum area variation between extremal regions at varying intensity thresholds, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'MaxAreaVariation' and a positive scalar value. Increasing this value returns a greater number of regions, but they may be less stable. Stable regions are very similar in size over varying intensity thresholds. Typical values range from 0.1 to 1.0.

However, as [penelope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18614498/4726250) says, the original paper is very useful for a more deep understanding of the full process. Also, I give [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/det_eval_files/vibes_ijcv2004.pdf) reference of a very interesting comparison between well-known feature detectors.