# How to assign value to cvMSERParams in MSER?

Tags: opencv

Could anyone provide some ballpark for these 9 parameters in MSER class? These 9 inputs are the below: 
int delta, int minArea, int maxArea,
double maxVariation, double minDiversity,
int maxEvolution, double areaThreshold, double minMargin, int edgeBlurSize

Comment: This stackoverflow Q&A fairly well addresses my question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647500/exact-meaning-of-the-parameters-given-to-initialize-mser-in-opencv-2-4-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation presented [this blog](http://experienceopencv.blogspot.de/2011/01/mser-mscr-detectors.html) and in the [VLFeat website](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/mser.html) should give you a good overview of all the parameters.. I would also recommend reading [their paper](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/publications/pubobjects/docvpr2006) to get a good handle on the math..

Hope this helps.